# How can i fill the pallet rack storage without an order?

Tags: javascript, anylogic

I would like to have full pallet rack storages when I start the model. Is this possible without unloading docks and without orders? I would like to create a model where I have pallets in my storage racks which get picked up by forklifts and transported into trucks. If it is possible, how can I automatically fill my pallet rack storages? Like you can see on the picture, that i get full pallet racks without this unlaoding dock and the orders. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWZM5.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. Two options I see:

1. create a warmup period that is long enough to fill your pallets (again, you need to do this manually)
2. create a specific "RackStore" element that uses a very large ResourcePool of fake storing agents that have a very high speed. Make them fill your racks manually at the start. In essence, you will still have a warmup period but it will be shorter

I recommend option 1 as it is the normal approach to sim modelling anyway :-)

Comment: When I choose option 2, is there a option to fill up the rack system when the pallet racks have free space? So for example the pallet racks get empty during the simulation, I would like to refill them immediately.